# Flutter audio_service stream update notification with IcyMetadata

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

I want to to a streamApp for just one stream/url.

In the audio_service example there is an MediaItem added in the AudioPlayerHandler.

This works so fahr but when IcyMedata updated the notification … obviously … has title and stuff from the added MediaItem. In the app i can update per _audioHandler.playbackstate and _player.icyMetadata!.info!.title! and some sting.splits(' - ') I can update Infos in the app with  StreamBilder.

Also tried a dirty hack to add title in the PlaybackState object by changing the audio_service and add a title as property and connect it in the custom AudioHandler with _player.icy … .

But there must be a proper way to set metadata new or by this framework by itself. _audioHandler.updateMediaItem does nothing so far to the notification info, this is what i need!

I found a addStream … my try (Snippets)

```
Stream<MediaItem> _item()  async* {   MediaItem(
      id: "http://stream.drumandbass.fm:9012",
      title: "TEST",
      artist: "Hello",
      album: "Album",
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5739820),
      genre: 'Drum and Bass',
      artUri: Uri.parse('test.jpg'));
}

Future<AudioPlayerHandler> initAH() async {
  return await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => AudioPlayerHandler(),
    config: const AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.ryanheise.myapp.channel.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio playback',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
    ),
  );
class AudioPlayerHandler extends BaseAudioHandler {
  /// Initialise our audio handler.
  AudioPlayerHandler() {
    // So that our clients (the Flutter UI and the system notification) know
    // what state to display, here we set up our audio handler to broadcast all
    // playback state changes as they happen via playbackState...
    _player.playbackEventStream.map(_transformEvent).pipe(playbackState);
    // ... and also the current media item via mediaItem.
    mediaItem.addStream(_item());
    // Load the player.
    _player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(mediaItem.value!.id)));
  }
 // some play stop the rest of the example of audio_service
```

Widget:

```
FutureBuilder<AudioPlayerHandler>(
                        future: initAH(),
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<AudioPlayerHandler> snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                            // while data is loading:
                            return Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            );
                          } else {
                            _audioHandler = snapshot.data!;

                            loaded = true;

                            // data loaded:

                            return Container();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
```

… with _player.add(MediaItem()); like in example i get a snapshot.hasData  but with addStream loaded keeps false.

I thankful for any tips to handle this issue properly.

thx,

Tom

Comment: Did you check the audio_service [FAQ](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-update-an-existing-mediaitem)?

Comment: Just enlighten me how to update the notifications.

Comment: Have it, THX!  Had to add "add" to extended BaseAudioHandler which add MediaItem to mediaItem.

Answer (score 0):

As you not seeing the notification. please check your android configuration.

```
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" ...>
  <!-- ADD THESE TWO PERMISSIONS -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
  
  <application ...>
    
    ...
    
    <!-- EDIT THE android:name ATTRIBUTE IN YOUR EXISTING "ACTIVITY" ELEMENT -->
    <activity android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity" ...>
      ...
    </activity>
    
    <!-- ADD THIS "SERVICE" element -->
    <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService"
        android:exported="true" tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- ADD THIS "RECEIVER" element -->
    <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver"
        android:exported="true" tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver> 
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: If you have to gues you should probably better find a different question to answer. Alternatively ...

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

if you are update you metadata you have just added updatemetadata of your view dart file otherwise set in initstate
like below

before you Add udioHandler.updateMediaItem() you need to update your  Audiohandler file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A9Ji.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkV0j.png)

its work for me